# Is there a way to determine whether a flag was set when using `flag.VisitAll`?

Tags: go

I'm using go's native `"flag"` package.

Built into it is the ability to visit all currently defined flags, using [`flag.VisitAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#VisitAll).

I'm trying to build a snippet that tries to fetch the value for that flag from an environment variable if one exists and in-case the flag was not set, and I can't find a way to determine whether a specific flag was set or not.

Is there any way to achieve that without implementing new parameter types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function to walk over the unset command line flags. This functionality can be implemented, however, by taking the difference between the flags returned by [`VisitAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#VisitAll) and [`Visit`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Visit); the former walks over all flags, while the latter walks over set flags:

```
func UnsetFlags(fs *flag.FlagSet) []*flag.Flag {
    var unset []*flag.Flag
    fs.VisitAll(func(f *flag.Flag) {
        unset = append(unset, f)
    })
    fs.Visit(func(f *flag.Flag) {
        for i, h := range unset {
            if f == h {
                unset = append(unset[:i], unset[i+1:]...)
            }
        }
    })
    return unset
}
```

You can use that function after your `flag.Parse` call to set any unset flags to their environment value:

```
for _, f := range UnsetFlags(flag.CommandLine) {
    v := os.Getenv(f.Name)
    f.Value.Set(v)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `flag.VisitAll` sounds a bit convoluted; I'd suggest getting the environment variable with a sane default and using it as the flag's default value - meaning the environment variable will be the fallback if the flag isn't set:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func GetEnvDefault(key, def string) string {
    v := os.Getenv(key)

    if v == "" {
        return def
    }

    return v
}

func main() {
    // Uncomment to test behaviour
    // os.Setenv("SERVER_NAME", "donaldduck")

    var serverName string

    flag.StringVar(&serverName, "n", GetEnvDefault("SERVER_NAME", "mickeymouse"), "The human name for the server")
    flag.Parse()

    fmt.Println(serverName)
}
```

See: https://play.golang.org/p/ixDsXH31cBF

Comment: Great solution, and yet, I would like an answer to my original question for whether it's possible to determine if a flag was set without comparing to the default value.